# How to use separate files for classes in typescript?

Tags: typescript, commonjs

I am figuring out how to build a typescript app where all classes are saved in separate .ts files. I am using VS Code. The compile task seems to be working correctly (.ts files get transpiled to .js files), but when I load my main.js file into my HTML page I get this javascript error:

```
Can't find variable: require
```

My typescript code:

```
// __________ car.ts __________ 
class Car {
    color: string;

    constructor(color: string) {
        this.color = color;
        console.log("created a new " + color + " car");
    }
}
export = Car;

// __________ main.ts __________ 
import Car = require('car');

class Startup {
    public static main(): number {
        console.log('Hello World');
        var c = new Car("red");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

My tsconfig file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap":  true
    },
     "files": [
        "car.ts",
        "main.ts"
    ]
}
```

What step am I missing here? Why does javascript need something called 'require' ? Or is there another way to work with classes in separate files?

Comment: You need to install the `require` library. That's part of node.js.

Comment: Don't use ES6 modules then. Use internal modules/namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` function is a [part](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_require_id) of NodeJS. In order to make `require` work in browsers, you need to install [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html).

If you want to use internal modules, add `outFile` to your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap":  true,
        "outFile": "app.js"
    },
     "files": [
        "car.ts",
        "main.ts"
    ]
}
```

and add `<script src="app.js"></script>` in your `index.html` file.

Comment: My original goal is to split up classes in separate .ts files. I don't really want to install yet another dependency. Is there no simpler way to work with code separated in files?

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-splitting-across-files - for internal modules. TypeScript has alsow external modules but even though many people recommend that I don't find them that great for browsers.

Comment: Still the same problem. When I add "module Vehicles" around my Car class, and then try to instantiate a new Vehicle.Car() from another .ts file, the editor complains that "Vehicle" is not known.

Comment: You need to make sure that your `.ts` file is in `tsconfig.json` and that you reference the file by the comment `/// <reference path="relative/path/to/vehicle.ts" />`.

Comment: You should also add `outFile` (see my answer) and you don't need no `import` commands.

Comment: I have reposted the question with the code I now have, including the outfile. The modules are not yet recognized :-/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33874071/typescript-internal-module-not-recognized-by-vs-code

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: [TypeScript-Handbook: Splitting Across Files](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-splitting-across-files):

To reference the file to each other while coding use `///<reference path="someOtherScript.ts" />` at the very top of each file

> First, we can use concatenated output using the `--out` flag to compile all of the input files into a single JavaScript output file:
>   `tsc --out sample.js Test.ts`

Put `"outFile": "app.js"` in `"compilerOptions": {`

---

You can have all `.ts` files compiled in one `.js` file. That's what I'm using all the time. One JS-File but clean TypeScript-Code.

In Visual Studio it's `<TypeScriptOutFile>myfile.js</TypeScriptOutFile>`. Might be similar in Visual Code?

Comment: Yes, but then the TS editor complains that "Car" is not known. Only in javascript is "Car" known because all the files are compiled into one file.

Comment: ok wait, the solution is.. referencing: `///<reference path="someOtherScript.ts" />`

Comment: Where do you put this line? In VS Code, this seems not to be allowed (the whole line is underlined in red)

Comment: at the very top of each file, see my answer

Comment: Is it the solution for your Problem? Can I do something else for you?

Comment: It's not working... the car.ts file now still gets compiled to a js file (which should not be necessary) and also the import is not working. I will repost the code in a new question to make the problem clearer.

Comment: You don't need import here. Did you configure it to be output in one JavaScript-File yet? I added some extra Info to the answer

Comment: I have reposted the question using the tips from everyone here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33874071/typescript-internal-module-not-recognized-by-vs-code

Comment: I certainly won't! The difference between external and internal modules has been clarified already, the only problem is that the syntax apparently is still wrong :(

Comment: to be honest I never used modules yet, and I have some very big TypeScript Profject with tons of files. But please check the Manual: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules