# Typescript internal module not recognized by VS Code

Tags: json, typescript

I am trying to separate my typescript classes in separate files using internal modules. However, the main.ts file will not load or recognize the sub modules.

**main.ts**

```
/// <reference path="Car.ts" />
module Vehicles {
    var c = new Vehicles.Car("red");
}
```

**car.ts**

```
module Vehicles {
    export class Car {
        color: string;
        constructor(color: string) {
            this.color = color;
            console.log("created a new " + color + " car");
        }
    }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap":  true, 
        "out": "everything.js main.ts car.ts"
    }
}
```

**Update**: edited the "out" flag in tsconfig to try and compile main.ts and car.ts into everything.js - this is the last part that is not working: everything.js is not created. Instead, VS Code creates a main.js and a car.js. It seems that the "out" flag is ignored. I have also tried "outFile" with the same result.

Comment: Your `out` is wrong. It should be just `"outFile": "main.js". Try to add `export` in front of `module`.

Comment: Also, the compiler still creates a "car.js" file, which should not be necessary?

Comment: Your editor may create `car.js` but that's not the main problem. Please post the content of generated `main.js` too.

Comment: Hey, it seems to be working now! I can finally include internal modules from separate files. Thanks for all the help! Apparently, I can even leave out the 'files' option in tsconfig.json. The only problem now is that the TS files are not yet concatenated into one big JS file.

Comment: Yes, `files` is not necessary. I don't use the option. We use `gulp-typescript` for compiling `.ts` files because we can compile incrementally the code then which is faster.

Comment: So you don't use the internal task runner of VS Code? (or VS Studio?)

Comment: I don't use VS Studio. We use WebStorm and https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript#basic-usage. However, it's up to you. Visual Studio is a great IDE, I would stick with that.

Comment: Visual Studio *Code* is very diffrent then Visual Studio for this problem. I use Visual Studio, and I don't even need to make `/// <reference ...` or some weird conig files :P

Comment: Yes, but VS Studio is not available for mac :) Also, VS Code is quite fast and has a very clean user interface (quite contrary to VS Studio). The documentation for VS Code is truly horrible though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**main.ts**

```
/// <reference path="car.ts" />
var c = new Car("red");
```

**car.ts**

```
class Car {
    color: string;
    constructor(color: string) {
        this.color = color;
        console.log("created a new " + color + " car");
    }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap":  true, 
        "outFile": "main.js"
    },
    "files": [
        "main.ts",
        "car.ts"
    ]
}
```

**tasks.json**

> *Kokodoko*: I finally found the problem! You have to OMIT the "args" option inside "tasks.json", only then will the arguments in
>   tsconfig.json be used! I found the answer here:
>   github.com/Microsoft/typescript/wiki/tsconfig.json. It says: When
>   input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json files are
>   ignored

---

For further information about Modules, don't forget to have a look at the [TypeScript Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-splitting-across-files)

Comment: You missed the Vehicles module

Comment: The Typescript Handbook literally states that you can concatenate multiple .ts files into one .js file using the --out flag. This part is still not working in VS Code with the above config file. Actually, the "out" flag is completely ignored!

Comment: the `--out` flag is for use in console, don't expect it to work in `tsconfig.json`
someone hinted to use `outFile`, did you try this? btw. why don't you use Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Yup, also tried outfile. What's confusing about this is that microsoft's own Typescript documentation does not seem to apply to their own product VS Code... :( I do like VS Code though! It's fast and clean. It's just hard to configure. VS Studio is not available for mac. Also I find that tool somewhat bloated for these simple purposes.

Comment: oh a mac, ok. But yeah i agree its a nice little Programm. According to: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript you can have a "tasks.json" file, with commands and arguments

Comment: I finally found the problem! You have to OMIT the "args" option inside "tasks.json", only then will the arguments in tsconfig.json be used! I found the answer here: https://github.com/Microsoft/typescript/wiki/tsconfig.json. It says: When input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json files are ignored.

Comment: well do the one or the other. I think using `tasks.json` would be the clean way of doing it ;)

Answer (score 1):

To compile several .ts files into one big .js file using a VS Code task, you need to remove the 'args' from tasks.json and add the "out" argument to tsconfig.json

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap":  true,
        "out": "myapp.js"
    }
}
```

Note:
When input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json files are ignored.