# How to compile several Typescript files on Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I'm on Linux, Visual Studio Code. I have a project that has several .ts (typescript) files, and I need to compile them all at once.

The problem is that I have those files in the /src folder, and I want to compile them to another folder, so I have to also specify the output folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> so I have to also specify the output folder.

Use `outDir` in `tsconfig.json`

> Only using `tasks.json`

Then provide `--outDir dirPath` as a flag to `tsc`.

Comment: I don't seem to have a tsconfig.json... only tasks.json

Comment: then use `--outDir` compiler flag

Comment: would you add the `tasks.json` solution to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap":  true, 
        "outFile": "main.js"
    },
    "files": [
        "main.ts",
        "car.ts"
    ]
}
```

**tasks.json**

You have to OMIT the "args" option inside "tasks.json", only then will the arguments in tsconfig.json be used! I found the answer here: http://github.com/Microsoft/typescript/wiki/tsconfig.json. It says: When input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json files are ignored

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33874319/4339170